# Representing a matrix as unique scalar numbers in certain range

Tags: c, matrix, hash

I am trying to find a way to represent a **36*36 matrix** as **4 different numbers in a certain range (-2.0 to 2.0)**, but I'm struggling to find the best way to achieve this.

The goal is to "generate" 4 unique **floating-point** "coordinates" based on one input matrix. In other words, some sort of a hashing algorithm.

The numbers in the matrix **won't necessarily be unique numbers and the order (position) of a number matters**, i.e.

```
| 1, 2, 3 |             | 1, 3, 2 |                 | 5, 2, 3 |
| 5, 5, 6 |             | 5, 5, 6 |                 | 5, 1, 6 |
```

should yield distinctly different results.

The matrix itself is stored as an **array of unsigned integers** (no more than 2 digits, 0 included). It would be preferable if the method **will be able to keep the outcomes from the range limits, and the outcomes from different matrices would yield a noticeable amount of variation** (ie, if one matrix yields 1.0000001 and another 1.0000003 — not great).

Lastly, the method doesn't have to be scientifically/mathematically valid, but it HAS to be **consistent and repeatable**, meaning, one particular matrix would always yield the same result.

The language I'm working with is C and I would appreciate immensely any help and advice you guys could offer.
Thanks!

*Edit:*
This has nothing to do with security/cryptography/rocket science, I don't expect to have every possible permutation to be mapped to a unique outcome, don't require 0 collisions, exceptional speed, or anything of that sort, nor do I worry if the method is somewhat magic. Simply a way to boil a matrix down to 4 numbers, scattered around enough, so that if I'll do the same for 10 matrices, the results would be somewhat different

For example, I can represent a matrix as a scalar using a Frobenius norm, Adler-32, or any other similar method. What might be a decent approach to generate 4 numbers in the desired range, based on that norm\check\hash?

Comment: There are 100000...0000 (2592 zeros) such 36*36 integer matrices. There are 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936 sets of 4 64-bit numbers (floating point numbers are less expressive than that because not all bit combinations are good floating point numbers). The difference is 2515 decimal orders of magnitude, so you need to lower your expectations by at least that amount (actually more because you have a set of strict requirements for your output).

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to crunch the numbers, but unfortunately, my expectations are still that high:)

Comment: Well, if you want **4** numbers, you can traverse the matrix in four different ways (row-major, column-major, all the diagonals, all the anti-diagonals) applying the same transformation to four state variables, say rotate the bits by three to the left and add one element of the matrix. At the end you can transform the four states into 4 floating-points numbers. I have no idea if this could have any good properties other than giving the same two first numbers for diagonal matrices.

Comment: So use a hash function such as SHA-256 and use the bits to make up floating point numbers. One bit for the sign, one bit for the exponent, and however many you need for the mantissa. Take 4 of those and you are set.

Comment: both of these sound great, thank you and I'll try them out!

as for having numbers in the desired range, could you perhaps suggest to me a method I could use for making sure the numbers I get are in range, other than using a scale function (as I won't know the range of the input)

I do realize this all sounds a bit hocus pocus, but as I've said, it doesn't have to be scientifically valid, only repeatable. And I genuinely appreciate the ideas, thanks!